# Как удалить определенное количество ключей из массива?

Tags: php, массивы

У меня имеется массив

```
$keys = ["row1", "row2", "row3", "row4"]; //сам массив
$countToDelete = 3; //количество для удаления
```

Я понимаю, как удалить один ключ

```
$item= '';
  foreach ($keys as $key => $key1) {
     $item= $key1;
     unset($keys[$key]);
     sort($keys);
     break;
}
```

Но как я могу удалить данное количество $countToDelete из массива?

Comment: `array_splice` с нужными параметрами.

Comment: добавить к вышеприведенному коду счетчик?